# Backreferencing in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have a text file which has lines like

```
![](screeshot-3.jpg)
The above screenshot shows how you can delete posts by tags.

![](screeshot-4.jpg)
The above screenshot shows how you can delete posts by custom taxonomies.
```

I want to replace these lines with (note that the line number is retrieved from the filename of the previous line)

```
3. The above screenshot shows how you can delete posts by tags.

4. The above screenshot shows how you can delete posts by custom taxonomies.
```

Other lines should not be edited.

I am able to write a regular expression to match the number, but I am not sure how to reference this number again while replacing.

Kindly let me know how to do it in awk.

**Update**: Kindly note that I can't use GNU version and it needs to work both in Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you constrained to using awk?

Comment: @devnull Unfortunately yes, since this is part of a bigger awk script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to split previous line with characters `.` and `-`, and extract the second position, save in variable and use it for each line that is not blank:

```
awk '
    $0 ~ /^!\[\]/ { 
        split($0, arr, /[-.]/)
        num = arr[2]
        next 
    } 
    num {
        print num ". " $0
        num = 0
        next
    } 
    { print }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
3. The above screenshot shows how you can delete posts by tags.

4. The above screenshot shows how you can delete posts by custom taxonomies.
```

---

**EDIT**: Sorry. I didn't read that you cannot use the `GNU` version. I've commented the pattern `\S` that is not supported with `[^[:blank:]]`. I hope it works now.

Comment: This removes the `![](screeshot-4.jpg)` lines, but does not add the line numbers.

Comment: Thanks it works now. One quick question. Any specific reason for using `$1` in the first condition and `$0` in the second condition? We could just use `$0` in both cases right?

Comment: @Sudar: Yes. It's the same in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found one more issue, but was able to fix it based on your code. If there were more lines after the last line, then all those lines were also getting replaced with line numbers. I have edited your answer to fix that as well.

Comment: @Sudar: Ah, ok. You only want to replace the next one and use a flag for that. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk for the extension to `match()`:

```
gawk '
    match($0, /^!\[\].*-([0-9]+)\.jpg/, m) {
        printf "%d. ", m[1]
        next
    }
    1
' file.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to use GNU awk :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with perl , then you can use the below version:

```
perl -lne 'if(/^\!.*-([\d]+)\.jpg/)
           {$a=$1}
           elsif(/^[a-zA-Z]/)
           {print "$a \. $_"}' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, I am restricted to `awk` right now